# How to link buttons with lines based in graphs

Tags: c#, button, graph, custom-controls

I have a "button creator"(that creates my own custom buttons) in my form and I need to, after creating some buttons in the form, clicking in 2 random ones to connect then with a simple line (can be a `System.Drawing.Pen`). And i should use some kind of graph logical connection to do it. But I have no idea how I should do. Any code suggestions? Thank You

Comment: Code the paint event of the form and do a few e.Grphics.DrawLines(..) there once you know what you actually want. If you can't understand what _'some kind of graph logical connection'_ means you are not alone.

Comment: My Problem is not with the lines, but with where to put them. Because I should click in 2 buttons and make them "auto connect". Understand @TaW ?

Comment: yes. So you need to a) remember the last clicked button b) when a diffenrent button is clicked process them as a line-couple c) forget the remembered button. 'process' means: add the pair of buttons to a growing list<T> where T is a data structure that can hold two buttons, maybe a Tuple. Aslo call Invalidate on the form.

Comment: -  In the Paint event you loop over that list and draw a line for each pair from item1 as button location to item2.. Note that all buttons can and should use the same click event where you can and need to cast the `sender` param to Button. Come back with more questions when have done that ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I solved it! Thank you @TaW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
// two variables we will need:
Button lastBtn = null;
List<Tuple<Button, Button>> buttons = new List<Tuple<Button, Button>>();

void commonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn == null) return;
    if (lastBtn == null) { lastBtn = btn; return; }
    else if (btn == lastBtn) { lastBtn = null; return; }
    else { buttons.Add(new Tuple<Button, Button>(lastBtn, btn)); lastBtn = null; }
    Invalidate();
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach ( Tuple<Button, Button> t in buttons)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.RoyalBlue, t.Item1.Location, t.Item2.Location);
    }
}
```

When creating your buttons hook each up with the common click event:

```
yourButtonClass btn = new yourButtonClass()..
..
btn.Click += commonButton_Click;
```

This always draw lines from and to the upper left corner. Using the middle instead or a smart loaction on an edge the is cloest to the other button if left for you. In the latter case you could also add start- and endcaps to the pen, if you want to.